# How to set the redirect uri in the stack overflow rest api

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, stackexchange-api

I am trying to authorize google app script to the stack overflow rest api.

My script asks me to open the authorization window and everything looks good from there except after I have authorized the app I get.

> `redirect_uri` is not under the registered domain for this application

The redirect URI app script is creating is as follows.

> https://script.google.com/macros/d/1iGFdsYBrkOTRYdyv0A81xITdFetvhfxcR_s_3iOj0dyds_Zbk1wzGAG9/usercallback

I have searched all over and I cant seem to figure out how to configure the redirect uri in my client for stack overflow API.

[image]

Comment: Set `OAuth Domain` to `https://script.google.com/macros/d/1iGFdsYBrkOTRYdyv0A81xITdFetvhfxcR_s_3iOj0dyds_Zbk1wzGAG9/usercallback`?

Comment: From the [Stack Exchange API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication): "`redirect_uri` - must be under an apps registered domain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### stackApps side:

In your situation, please set the Stackoverflow side as follows.

- `OAuth Domain` is `script.google.com`.
- `Application Website` is `https://script.google.com/macros/d/1iGFdsYBrkOTRYdyv0A81xITdFetvhfxcR_s_3iOj0dyds_Zbk1wzGAG9/usercallback`.

### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
var tokenExchangeUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token"
```

#### To:

```
var tokenExchangeUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json"
```

And, in your script, the scope is not included. So, please modify `getService_()` as follows.

```
function getService_() {
  return OAuth2.createService('StackOverflow')
      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(authorizationUrl)
      .setTokenUrl(tokenExchangeUrl)
      .setScope(scope) // Added

      // Set the client ID and secret.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
      // complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}
```

And, I think that the sample request is required to be modified. So, how about the following sample?

#### From:

```
var url = authorizationUrl;


var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
  }
});
```

#### To:

```
var url = `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/me/inbox?site=stackoverflow&key=${key}&access_token=${service.getAccessToken()}`;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

- By this modification, the access token can be retrieved and the inbox can be retrieved using the access token.

#### Note:

- As additional information, the whole modified script is as follows.

```js
var CLIENT_ID = [REDACTED];
var CLIENT_SECRET = [REDACTED]
var key = [REDACTEd]

var authorizationUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth"
var tokenExchangeUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json"
var scope = "read_inbox"

/**
 * Authorizes and makes a request to the Stackoverflow API.
 */
function run() {
  var service = getService_();
  console.log(service.getRedirectUri())
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/me/inbox?site=stackoverflow&key=${key}&access_token=${service.getAccessToken()}`;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
        authorizationUrl);
  }
}

/**
 * Reset the authorization state, so that it can be re-tested.
 */
function reset() {
  getService_().reset();
}

/**
 * Configures the service.
 */
function getService_() {
  return OAuth2.createService('StackOverflow')
      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(authorizationUrl)
      .setTokenUrl(tokenExchangeUrl)
      .setScope(scope)

      // Set the client ID and secret.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
      // complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}

/**
 * Handles the OAuth callback.
 */
function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService_();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied.');
  }
}

/**
 * Logs the redict URI to register.
 */
function logRedirectUri() {
  Logger.log(OAuth2.getRedirectUri());
}
```

#### Reference:

- [apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250389/discussion-on-answer-by-tanaike-how-to-set-the-redirect-uri-in-the-stack-overflo).